# How can I create a linebreak between the chapter name/number and chapter title in the ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I'm using the `Memoir` class and I'm trying to format the table of contents for a document I'm working on. Currently, the ToC arranges entries in the following way:

```
<<chapter name>> <<chapter number>> <<chapter title>>
```

E.g.

```
Chapter 1 Introduction
Appendix A Specifications
```

I'd prefer if chapter entries were formatted like this:

```
<<chapter name>> <<chapter number>>
<<chapter title>>
```

E.g.

```
Chapter 1
Introduction

Appendix A
Specifications
```

I've looked through the [Memoir manual](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) but haven't managed to find anything that's proved helpful yet.

**EDIT**

Added MWE and image:

```
\documentclass[openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{memsty}

\renewcommand*{\cftchaptername}{\chaptername\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftappendixname}{Appendix\space}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}

\section{Bar}

\chapter{Baz}

\appendix
\chapter{Misc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sure thing, added.

Comment: You should not be using `memsty`, it is only for building the `memoir` manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not in the manual as it might not be that common, plus it is not that easy to do with a simple configuration. Here is a suggestion

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@chapapp}[3]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \cftchapterbreak
    \vskip \cftbeforechapterskip
    {%\leftskip \cftchapterindent\relax
     \memRTLleftskip \cftchapterindent\relax
%%%     \rightskip \@tocrmarg
     \memRTLrightskip \@tocrmarg
%%%     \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parfillskip -\memRTLrightskip
     \parindent \cftchapterindent\relax
     \@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \let\@cftbsnum \cftchapterpresnum
     \let\@cftasnum \cftchapteraftersnum
     \let\@cftasnumb \cftchapteraftersnumb
     \def\@chapapp@head{#3}%
     \settowidth{\@tempdima}{\cftchapterfont\@chapapp@head}%
     \addtolength{\@tempdima}{\cftchapternumwidth}%
     %% this line have to be out commented
     %\advance\memRTLleftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\memRTLleftskip
     {\cftchapterfont {#1}}\nobreak
     \cftchapterfillnum{#2}}
  \fi}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\cftchapteraftersnumb{\par}
```

We basically need `\l@chapapp` (which typesets chapters and appendices in the ToC) to stop increasing the left margin

---

Addition:

You can add `\nopagebreak`, but IMO the best solution is to make the length `\cftbeforechapterskip` more flexible. By default `\cftbeforechapterskip` is not that flexible. So I usually use something similar to

```
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{1.0em plus 0.2em minus 0.3em}
```

i.e., it can stretch some and shrink some. That leads to better results.

BTW: you might also want to use

```
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
```

in order to kill of any stretch between paragraphs over all in the document.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work pretty well. A lot of it is over my head so I have to ask how I could modify that to change the space between the two lines, if that's possible.

Comment: Got it, nevermind. Changed `{\cftchapterfont {#1}}\nobreak` to `{\vspace{<<X>>}\cftchapterfont {#1}}\nobreak`

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Why, you can just add that to `\cftchapteraftersnumb`

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean. I tried adding `\renewcommand\cftchapteraftersnumb{\vspace{<<X>>}}` immediately before the code you provided and that didn't seem to have an effect on the spacing.

Comment: `\renewcommand\cftchapteraftersnumb{\par\vspace{1em}}`

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed the fact that you were already redefining it after the rest of the code. You've already done more than enough so I don't mind if you don't have an answer for this, but is there a way to ensure that there's no page break between the two lines? It's not currently an issue but it might become one as the ToC changes.

Comment: @Tagc see my update

Comment: Thanks. I tested it out on a 'broken' version of the ToC (one with an unwanted page break), and tried your recommended approach. I had to make the range a little bigger (`\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{1.0em plus 0.5em minus 0.6em}`) but it worked.